# Code in R program for multiply

Tags: r

I have some question about code in R program. When we want to find `1+2+3+4+5`, we use `x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)` then `sum <- sum(x)`. How I can write the code to compute `1*2*3*4*5` in R?

Comment: Um. you can just type `1*2*3*4*5` and hit enter?

Comment: Is there a function like sum, mean and sd? because my real numbers are very large.

Comment: Yes, I've already posted an answer below.

Comment: Thank you, @AnandaMahto. I am very foolish in programming.

Comment: No, it is not equivalent between sum(x) for multiplication. I am only exemplify the function. And the next time, I will improve my writing. @AnandaMahto

Answer (score 2):

By the sounds of it, you are looking for the `prod` function:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
prod(x)
# [1] 120
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `Reduce`, though `prod` will be *much* faster

```
Reduce("*", x)
[1] 120
```

Comment: Could you tell me? What is the star (*) in that function? Thanks.

Comment: It's the multiplication operator